# How do i add Toolbar to this layout?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

Layout XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'd like to add a `Toolbar` to the top of the Activity (similar to an ActionBar) something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It doesn't matter where i include this View in the layout (tried basically everywhere), i always get an `InflateException`.

The `appcompat-v7` library project is (supposedly) handled by Eclipse, referenced as a library project, using the latest (22.1.1) version. The Activity extends `AppCompatActivity` (tried with `Activity` also).

No idea what's wrong, i'd appreciate any advice.
Please tell if you need any more details.

Comment: Put the toolbar at the end of your content `RelativeLayout`, make sure your theme extends `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and don't forget to call `setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`.

Comment: Please add the code from your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your main xml like

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00ffee"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Add This in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/color_primary_text</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I dropped the android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" line, switched the order of the Toolbar and  the ViewPager, and set a transparent background to the Toolbar for an overlay style.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```